# Delete previous word in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, shortcuts

In almost any other application, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the previous word when editing text. In Excel 2013, it jumps the view to the active cell.

Is there an alternate shortcut for "delete previous word" in Excel? Is there a way to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>to this functionality so it's consistent with most other applications?

EDIT: To those coming across this later, the following AutoHotKey rule should do the trick:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN
    ^Backspace::
        Send ^+{Left}{Backspace}
        return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the functionality to delete the last word does not exist in Excel and there is no shortcut for it. Excel is not a word processor, so shortcuts will focus on other aspects.

N>B>: What do you means by "it jumps the view to the active cell"? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> does nothing in my Excel 2013. Not in edit mode and not in ready mode either.

Check if there are any add-ins that use the shortcut.

Comment: If the active cell is off-screen, Ctrl+Backspace will scroll/pan so that it is on-screen again.

Comment: I'm going to try to find an add-in that enables this shortcut, as I use it extensively.

Comment: Ended up going with an AutoHotKey rule that I was already using elsewhere (Notepad, the field you type in when renaming a file, etc) that maps "Ctrl+Backspace" to "Ctrl+Shift+Left, Backspace".

Comment: here is the autohokey script, put it in a file with extension .ahk and start it:
`^Backspace::Send ^+{Left} {Backspace}`

Answer (score 2):

When in edit mode (select cell and double click of press <kbd>F2</kbd>), you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><--</kbd> to select the previous word and then press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

That's my best suggestion.

Comment: This works with sharepoint excel so is nicer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question about 2 weeks ago but I have the solution without using Auto Hotkeys just ctrl + Shift + Backspace works wonders. GL!

Comment: This is the better answer. If OP cannot get used to using CTRL+SHIFT+BKSP in Excel, they can still use AHK but map it to this key combination instead. CTRL+SHIFT+LEFT may highlight the entire row depending on Point Mode being toggled on or off.

Comment: This is the BEST ANSWER

Answer (score 1):

To replicate<sup>*</sup> Word's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, do the following:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> followed by either two <kbd>Backspace</kbd>s or two <kbd>Delete</kbd>s.

The second <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> is not required if there is a space immediately to the left of the cursor as that space will be included in the selection.

When deleting multiple words, it is best to select them first with multiple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>s, and *then* delete the words.

<sup>*</sup> Note that Excel's shortcut does not perform exactly the same as Word's. Word is smart enough to always delete all the appropriate spaces, leaving just one, no matter where the cursor is. The Excel shortcut, on the other hand, just selects (and deletes) all the characters from the cursor to the start of the word to the left, strictly only deleting any intervening spaces.

---

The equivalent sequence for Word's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is, of course:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> followed by either <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Note that only one <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> is required if there is a non-space character immediately to the right of the cursor. Otherwise, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> sequence needs to be repeated, as the first sequence only selects the space.

---

**Caveat:**

Will not work unless a cell is double-clicked, <kbd>F2</kbd> is pressed, or the formula bar is clicked before entering the text. This can be worked-around after text entry has begun by clicking in the formula bar at the top of the screen.